# avoid transformation form xs:duration('P14M') to xs:duration('P1Y2M')

Tags: xsd, duration

If the input for a schema-attribute period (type xs: duration) is 'P14M' is there a transformation to P1Y2M. How is this transformation to be prevented?
I need the format P14M.
Thanks

Comment: POSTING WHAT YOU HAVE DONE SO FAR TO ACHIEVE THE GOAL WOULD HELP US TO US HELP YOU.

Comment: Which tools are you using?